# what is the frame name of a class in which it is extended?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, methods, jframe

I am creating an application with different look and feel!
I have created a JFrame Form in Netbeans which means I have a created a class which is extended JFrame like this:

```
 public class interFace extends javax.swing.JFrame
```

And I have created a method in which I have to pass two arguments one is a frame name and other is string! so what will be the frame name of my JFrame which is extended into my class?

**Method is like:**

```
 changeLaf(JFrame frame, String laf);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class MyFrame extends JFrame{

    public MyFrame() {

        changeLaf(this,"some string");
    }

    public void changeLaf(JFrame frame, String laf){
            // your code
    }

}
```

Use this to refer to pass the instance like above. `this` refers to the current object. Its not name its actually an `object` or can be reference as well.

If you are doing it using by instantiating the class then,

```
MyFrame mf = new MyFrame();
changeLaf(mf, "some string");
```

Comment: although this keyword wasn't just accepted! but I got the idea and done it!
 I used `MyFrame.this` instead of `this` only!

Comment: Thanks for informing that. Good to know that your problem is solved.